# Need a hand with a simple query

Tags: sql, count

I need a help with a query. I think is not so difficult.

I need to do a select with distinct and at the same time, do a count(*) of how many rows are returned by this distinct.

One example:

```
Table names>
Id   Name
1    john
2    john
3    mary
```

I need a query thats return:

```
Name    Total
john    2
mary    1
```

Comment: Who down voted this?  Even if simple once known, people are free to ask what they don't know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select name, count(*) from names group by name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM names GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, count(*) as occurrences FROM names GROUP BY name
```